# Python - Merge list elements and add as an element to another list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have a list in which each element is a single character. I want to somehow print out the contents of the list, joining the characters to form a word, but then take that word and append it as an element to a second list. Here's what I have so far:

```
def mergeListElements():
    charList = ['t', 'e', 's', 't', '3']
    for each in charList:
        wordList.append(print''.join(charList))

wordList = ['test1', 'test2']
    mergeListElements()

print '\n'.join(wordList)
```

I want the final output of the program to print wordlist out as:

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

I get the 'invalid syntax' error here:

```
    wordList.append(print''.join(charList))
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve this. I've tried separating it into it's own fuction, declaring the merge into a variable and then printing that, etc.

Any help appreciated guys, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The first line will join all of the separated items in your list.  Let's call this f.
The second line takes your list of words and adds our new word to it.

```
f = ''.join(charList)
wordList.append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop isn't necessary, because `''.join(charList)` concatenates charList.

`wordList.append(''.join(charList))`